# vl_covdet alternative in python

Tags: python, matlab

I am using matlab to detect sift features from an image using vl_feat command of vl_covdet
 but i want to calculate it in python i tried this code

```
        def process_image(self, imagename,resultname,params="--edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5"):
    """ process an image and save the results in a file"""


    if imagename[-3:] != 'pgm':
        #create a pgm file
        im = Image.open(imagename).convert('L')
        im.save('tmp.pgm')
        imagename = 'tmp.pgm'

    cmmd = str("/home/hassan/vlfeat/bin/glnxa64/sift "+imagename+" --output="+resultname+
            " "+params)
    os.system(cmmd)
    print 'processed', imagename, 'to', resultname
```

but it does not give me perfect answer like vl_covdet so is there any alternative to
 vl_covdet in python as there are options of AffineAdaptation and Orientation in vl_covdet
 in matlab but i cant find in python